# combining rows to dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have some data in this format, which i want to import in R, so far I use read.csv to read them, but every piece of ends up in its own line.

```
18.07.19
05:41:05
Information
18.07.19
05:43:48
Something
18.07.19
05:20:48
Text
18.07.19
01:16:45
```

so far good, but I need it to be ins this format:

```
18.07.19    05:41:05    Information
18.07.19    05:43:48    Something   
18.07.19    05:20:48    Text    
18.07.19    01:16:45
```

since I want to use the data as a dataframe.

I assume dcast could be the right approach, but I can't figure out what I have to pass as parameters.

Comment: Do you want combine every three rows into one row ?

Comment: @RonakShah: yes. every 3 lines as 1 row, with in total 3 columns (date, time, text)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hack, using `data.table::dcast` since you mentioned that:

```r
x <- read.csv(header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
18.07.19
05:41:05
Information
18.07.19
05:43:48
Something
18.07.19
05:20:48
Text
18.07.19
01:16:45")

x$i <- head(rep(1:3, times=ceiling(nrow(x) / 3)), n = nrow(x))
x$j <- head(rep(1:ceiling(nrow(x)), each=3), n = nrow(x))

data.table::dcast(x, j ~ i, value.var="V1")
#   j        1        2           3
# 1 1 18.07.19 05:41:05 Information
# 2 2 18.07.19 05:43:48   Something
# 3 3 18.07.19 05:20:48        Text
# 4 4 18.07.19 01:16:45        <NA>
```

(You can easily remove `j` and rename the column names.)

Answer (score 0):

Another hacky way in base R since it's just a one-column dataframe. We append `NA`'s to the missing values in the column and fill the matrix with values by specifying number of columns.

```
n <- 3
data.frame(matrix(c(df$V1, rep(NA, n - length(df$V1) %% n)),ncol = 3,byrow = TRUE))

#        X1       X2          X3
#1 18.07.19 05:41:05 Information
#2 18.07.19 05:43:48   Something
#3 18.07.19 05:20:48        Text
#4 18.07.19 01:16:45        <NA>
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("18.07.19", "05:41:05", "Information", 
"18.07.19", "05:43:48", "Something", "18.07.19", "05:20:48", 
"Text", "18.07.19", "01:16:45")), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = 
"data.frame")
```

Comment: I assume I did something wrong (or have another R version than yours) it shows "X1 X2 X3" "1   6  4 11" "2   6  3 18"...

Comment: @user2567875 yes, the column are factors. You need to convert it to characters. do `df$V1 <- as.character(df$V1)` and then run the above.

Comment: or read them in as strings the first time with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`